# Problems while running Yii2 kartik Export Extension

Tags: php, widget, yii2, yii-extensions

I'm new to Yii and I'm developing a database application that reads tables from MySQL. I needed the user to be able to export data as CSV or PDF, so I downloaded Kartik Yii2 Export Extension. I don't know how am I supposed to configure my settings to run this extension, I read the guide but I didn't understand how to fix this error:

Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
The "query" property must be an instance of a class that implements the QueryInterface e.g. yii\db\Query or its subclasses.

Here is my code:

Models/industrial.php:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Industrial extends ActiveRecord
{
}
```

controller/IndustrialController.php:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;


use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\data\Pagination;
use app\models\industrial;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;

class IndustrialController extends Controller
{


public function actionIndex()
{
$dataProvider=new ActiveDataProvider('Industrial', array(

'pagination'=>array(
'pageSize'=>20,
),
));
$query = industrial::find();

$pagination = new Pagination([
'defaultPageSize' => 20,
'totalCount' => $query->count(),
]);

$industrials = $query->orderBy('Company_Name')
->offset($pagination->offset)
->limit($pagination->limit)
->all();




return $this->render('index', [
'industrials' => $industrials,
'pagination' => $pagination,
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
]);



}
}
```

views/industrial/index.php:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\LinkPager;
?>
<h1>Industrial Companies</h1>
<ul>
<?php

use kartik\export\ExportMenu;

use kartik\grid\GridView;

$gridColumns = [
['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
'id',
'name',
[
'attribute'=>'Name',
'label'=>'Name',
'vAlign'=>'middle',
'width'=>'190px',
'value'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) { 
return Html::a($model->Name, '#', []);
},
'format'=>'raw'
],
'Name',
'Location',
'Telephone',

];
echo ExportMenu::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'columns' => $gridColumns,
'fontAwesome' => true,
'dropdownOptions' => [
'label' => 'Export All',
'class' => 'btn btn-default'
]
]) . "<hr>\n".
GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'columns' => $gridColumns,
'export' => [
'fontAwesome' => true,
]
]);



$array = (array) $industrials;



function build_table($array){

// start table

$html = '<table class="altrowstable" id="alternatecolor">';

// header row

$html .= '<tr>';

foreach($array[0] as $key=>$value){

$html .= '<th>' . $key . '</th>';

}

$html .= '</tr>';

// data rows

foreach( $array as $key=>$value){

$html .= '<tr>';

foreach($value as $key2=>$value2){

$html .= '<td>' . $value2 . '</td>';

}

$html .= '</tr>';

}

// finish table and return it

$html .= '</table>';

return $html;

}



echo build_table($array);

?>


<?= LinkPager::widget(['pagination' => $pagination]) ?>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the configuration of your activeDataProvider

I see no value assigned to the key 'query' such as follows

```
 $ dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider ([ 
      'query' => Post :: find (),
      'pagination' => [
      'pageSize' => 20,
      ],
 ]);
```

test with the following

```
actionIndex public function ()
{
    $ dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider ('Industrial', array (
        'query' => Industrial :: find (),
        'pagination' => array (
        'pageSize' => 20,
        ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an error code
you should write:

```
$ query = Industrial :: find ();
```

and not

```
$ query = industrial :: find ();
```

Industrial class begins with uppercase

Comment: Thank you, I changed it but it didn't work, still giving the same error!

Answer (score 0):

Add this under components in config/web.php in Yii2 folder, it will work

```
'modules' => [
        'gridview' => [
            'class' => '\kartik\grid\Module',
            ],
         ],
```